# How to post VHDL code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I saw many answers in which people have included supporting [VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL) code. I tried the same, but it is not working. What is the correct procedure to be followed when we include VHDL code with our answer?

Comment: "not working" is not an appropriate problem description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like any [other code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) on Stack Overflow: indent four spaces or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut to create a code block.

Answer (score -3):

You have to specify the language through a HTML comment. It is near the bottom of the link given by Qiu

```
<!-- language: vhdl -->

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
entity vector_test is
port (  CLOCK   : in std_logic;
        RESET   : in std_logic;
        INPUT   : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        OUTPUT  : out std_logic);
end entity;
```

Which should render correctly on Stack Overflow ( I already used it ) but strangely do not render on Meta Stack Overflow

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
entity vector_test is
port (  CLOCK   : in std_logic;
        RESET   : in std_logic;
        INPUT   : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        OUTPUT  : out std_logic);
end entity;
```

Other C code is not colored on the meta site.

```
typedef unsigned int u32;
```

Comment: Why downvotes ? Specifying the language speed up the syntax highlighting. Don't you experienced the same ?

Comment: The question is not _"How do I get syntax highlighting for VHDL code?"_, which your answer does in fact answer. The question is _"How do I **post a question containing VHDL code**?"_, meaning they currently (or at least, they couldn't 17 months ago when they asked this Meta question) can't post one. This means they either messed up the code formatting, or dumped a one-liner question with two hundred lines of code. Point being: if they were trying to and it was "not working", they got a message indicating why they were unable to post it.